# @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

Tags: javascript, firebase

***UPDATED CODE***

So this is making me crazy...I am creating a blog app (Vanilla Js + Firebase).

- onDeleteButton deletes a single blog post. It deletes both front end
  and backend. no error.
- onEditButton edits a single blog post. It works fine as well.
- When I first edit a post and after that delete the same post, it deletes from both back and and front end, seemingly works fine BUT in console log throws me and error: 
  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null.`
  The error message points at the `storeTitle.value = editPost.title;` line in onEditButton function.

> Why does onEditButton function gets called after deleting a post, but only once it has been edited once?

```
function onDeleteButton(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let id = event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('id');
    let deletePost = document.getElementById(id);
    firebase.database().ref('posts/' + id).remove();
    deletePost.parentNode.removeChild(deletePost);
}

function onEditButton(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let editButton = document.getElementById('edit');
    editButton.removeAttribute("hidden");
    let id = event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('id');
    let posts = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + id);
    let storeTitle = document.getElementById('blog-title');
    let storeContent = document.getElementById('blog-content');
    localStorage.setItem("postID", id);
    document.getElementById("blog-id-storage").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("postID");
    posts.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    let editPost = snapshot.val();
    storeTitle.value = editPost.title;
    storeContent.value = editPost.content;
    });
}


function enterEditingMode() {
    if (document.getElementById('editing-mode-button').innerHTML === "Exit editing mode") {
        exitEditingMode();
    }
    else {

        ...
            addDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", this.onDeleteButton); 
            addEditButton.addEventListener("click", this.onEditButton);

            })
    }

}
```

html:

```
<button id="editing-mode-button" onclick="enterEditingMode()" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Editing mode</button>
```

Comment: It will be helpful to see how the binding of `onEditButton` and `onDeleteButton` to their buttons in the code

Comment: I have edited the code above.

Comment: As many times I click on the edit button, when deleting the same post I get the error message the same amount of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same issue in the future, here is the solution.
On the editbutton function I used `posts.on('value', function(snapshot) {...}` so everytime I run this function once it was listening for changes, the code block in {} was running every time...So instead of posts.on, I had to use `posts.once('value', function(snapshot) {...}`. .once() without listening for changes

From firebase doc:

> Listen for value events
>   To read data at a path and listen for changes, use the on() or once() methods of firebase.database. Reference to observe events.